# How can I get relative path?

Tags: objective-c, path, warnings, relative-path

I'm programming on objective-c. I have 3 folders with 3 languages such as en, ru, fr with pictures 1.png, 2.png, 3.png. How can I get relative path for my pictures? How should I add this files in my project? 
I have some warnings. Its because I have the same name of sources.

```
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/Kate/Documents/XCode_progs/MyProject/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject/1.png
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/Kate/Documents/XCode_progs/MyProject/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject/2.png
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/Kate/Documents/XCode_progs/MyProject/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject/3.png
```

My code doesn't work:

```
CCSprite *button = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/1.png", lang]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your images to your project, that you can call:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"png"];
```

If you add localization to this resource (png image) (in XCode 4 choose image file and in Utility panel (on right hand) you can add different localizations), then in runtime iOS choose properly localized file automatically.